# PowerShell replace $env:USERPROFILE in prompt

Tags: command-line, powershell, find-and-replace, prompt

I mean to get in my PS 5.1 prompt

```
~\Documents
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\USER1\Documents
```

But while trying one of the "building blocks" I get an error

```
> $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation) -replace $env:USERPROFILE, '~'
The regular expression pattern C:\Users\USER1 is not valid.
At line:1 char:3
...
```

I mean to include this in

```
$ESC = [char]27
$BLUE="$ESC[1;34m"
$RESET="$ESC[0m"
function prompt  
{  
    $cwd = $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation) ;
    # $my_new_var=USE THE REPLACING COMMAND
    "$BLUE$my_new_var$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) $RESET"  
}
```

**How should I escape `$env:USERPROFILE` for this to work?**
**Would that work within my `prompt`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the replace you're looking for:

```
($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation).ToString().Replace($env:USERPROFILE, '~')
```

Comment: `ToString()`.... of course.... LOL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use format strings to expand variable inside Regex replace:

```
$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation) -replace ("{0}" -f $env:USERPROFILE), '~'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might run into trouble if you move above your $HOME directory. If you always want the last element of the path, I would use one of the following:

```
'~\{0} -f ($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation).Path.Split('\')[-1]
```

```
'~\{0}' -f (Split-Path ($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation).Path -Leaf)
```